# Add a custom OpenID provider to a Janrain widget

Tags: openid, identity, janrain

With the Janrain widget code, is it possible to add our own custom OpenID provider to the list? Like next to the Google / OpenID plugins.

Any clever code we may have missed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pro customers can create Custom UI sign in buttons for any OpenID provider. They are outside the normal widget workflow but work like any other sign in. For Plus customers this would need to be included in the widget.